# C#: How to add double quotes in variable

Tags: c#, silverlight

i am developing silverlight application. right now, i have an issue to pass string variable to sql statement, together with double quotes. i tried using this way:

```
string itemList;
string commaString = @"""";

for (int i = 0; i < TestList.Count; i++)
 {
   itemList += commaString + TestList[i].Code + commaString + " || ";
 }
```

itemList = "x.Code == " + itemList;

itemList = itemList.Removed(itemList.Length - 3);

but the variable passed is like this:

> " x.Code == \" 11001-111001 \"  || x.Code ==  \" 11016-111001 \"
>   "

i want it to be this way:

> x.Code == "11001-111001" || x.Code == "11016-111001"

i dont want the back slash. i want to pass this variable to sql select statement. is it possible to do this? can anybody help me? thank you...

***Updated:

my TestList currently have 2 values:

```
"11001-111001"
"11016-111001"
```

and then i want to combine these values in itemList to be:

> x.Code == "11001-111001" || x.Code == "11016-111001"

since i want to use this in sql statement. when combined, now becomes

> " x.Code == \"11001-111001\" || x.Code == \"11016-111001\" "

below is how i want to use the variable. i want to replace the codes with **itemList**:

```
private void GetAccountCodes()
{
  var r = _svc.AccountCodes.Where(x => x.Code == "11001-111001" || x.Code == "11016-111001").Select(x => x);
  _company.AccountCodes.LoadCompleted -= new EventHandler<LoadCompletedEventArgs>(AccountCodes_LoadCompleted);
  _company.AccountCodes.LoadCompleted += new EventHandler<LoadCompletedEventArgs>(AccountCodes_LoadCompleted);
  _company.AccountCodes.Clear(true);
  _company.AccountCodes.LoadAsync(r);
}

private void AccountCodes_LoadCompleted(object sender, LoadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  if (_company.AccountCodes!= null && _company.AccountCodes.Count() > 0)
  {
     //do something. but right now it returns no record            
  }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do inside `AccountCodes_LoadCompleted` ? You're filtering inside the first method by 2 codes. Do you mean you have a list of codes and not just 2 codes and you want to filter by that list instead of restricting it to 2 only ?

Comment: i have a list of codes entered by user (code list can be many, depend on user input), then i need to retrieved the details of the code list from database. thats why i will use the list to search the sql query...so, instead of retrieving all the codes from database, i can just get the details of the entered codes only.

Comment: AccountCodes_LoadCompleted will display the retrieved records from database. then, i can use it to do something else

Comment: So you want to change `.Where(x => x.Code == "11001-111001"....` to match a list of codes and not just 2 codes ?

Comment: yup thats why i put them in list...i just give example of 2 codes only

Comment: You can replace that with `.Where(x=> itemList.Contains(x.Code)).ToList()`

Comment: haa thanks user3185569 for that idea :) i will try this and let u know the result.wish me luck

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

You can use Contains for pass a list of items for a database linq query:

```
.Where(x=> itemList.Contains(x.Code)).ToList()
```

### Debugger escape characters:

As for the `\" part This is only the debugger showing the value like that.

Trying clicking the small magnifier icon or printing the value to the console, you'll get:

```
"11001-111001" || x.Code == "11016-111001" || "
```

See this image as a proof:

[image]

Those escape backslashes are added by the debugger only.

To add a single quote, you can use one of the below approaches:

```
string commaString = " \" "
```

Or:

```
string commaString = @" "" "
```

Comment: yes, when i debugged, this variable carried this kind of format...i am not using console. i want to use this variable for another function

Comment: @jeliey don't worry. It is just something added by the debugger. Just use `Console.WriteLine(itemList);` and check the output windows, you'll see that the string is just as you expect it to be. or click the tiny magnifier that visual studio provide for strings, you'll see that actual printable value for that string.

Comment: i will try to see the output...if this works, can we assign Console.WriteLine(itemList) as a variable?

Comment: @jeliey No need to assign `Console.WriteLine`. It is just for you to check if the string is correct or now. You don't need to modify your code. It is just perfectly fine.

Comment: @jeliey see the image in the answer to make it clear.

Comment: emm...but i need this codes to run sql query. thats why im sending this as a variable.

Comment: @jeliey or for sql use need to use x.Code == '11001-111001' . By using ' and not "

Comment: var r = _svc.Test.Expand("CodeCenter").Where(x => x.Code == "11001-111001" || x.Code == "11016-111001").Select(x => x); in my code, i run this with hardcoded codes...it works

Comment: @jeliey can you show the data inside `TestList` and how you're constructing the final query. Update your question and show that.

Comment: yup, im sure the codes is correct if we want to display the value on screen.but right now, to send it as a variable...it stills bring this format " \" 11001-111001 \" || x.Code == \" 11016-111001 \" || "

Comment: @jeliey What is the error returned by the database engine ?

Comment: no errors but the database returned no records since i am searching different codes. currently my codes is searching  \" 11001-111001 \" || x.Code == \" 11016-111001 \" not "11001-111001" || x.Code == "11016-111001"...thats why no record found

Comment: @jeliey do you see the `\` when you click the magnifier icon like shown in the picture in my answer ? If yes, please show the entire method that you use to construct the query. Edit your question and paste the entire method .

Comment: @jeliey I updated the answer. If the contains worked for you, please mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

user3185569 is right. It's just the debugger that shows that value. Nevertheless it might not be the best idea to concatenate the strings that way (remember: strings are immutable). I would use a StringBuilder() and string.Format() as follows:

```
StringBuilder itemList = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < TestList.Count; i++)
{
    itemList.Append(string.Format("\"{0}\" || ", TestList[i].Code));
}
```

This also improves readability.

Comment: using this method, i get the corrected format. {" && x.Code == "11001-111001" || x.Code == "11016-111001" "} .but i want remove this curly bracket {" "} to make this works...

Comment: but when i convert this to string(), it becomes the same again. "\" && x.Code == \"11001-111001\" || x.Code == \"11016-111001"

Comment: These curly brackets are shown by the debugger when displaying the contents of the StringBuilder, just as the '\' you saw. They aren't part of the string. Call itemList.ToString() and you won't see any curly brackets but the '\' are there again. This is how the debugger shows variable content, just as user3185569 pointed out.

Comment: so, u mean no ways to get the values i want?

Comment: Looking at your code, are you sure you really have to concatenate strings? I think you have to change the lambda expression x => x.Code == "11001-111001" || x.Code == "11016-111001" to iterate over TestList and return when x.Code equals the current item.

Comment: i have done that way.since the AccountCodes table has too many records (>1000), it is taking too much time to load all the records first before i can foreach the records to look for the codes user entered

Comment: A quote from the answer from user3185569 : **For SQL , you need to surround Strings with Single Quotes ' and not double ones ".** If you want to send your query as a string it has to be valid SQL.

Comment: Right now im not executing the query directly in sql...i need to use the variable in linq function thru silverlight application and connect to service. U can see my updated question, i showed u how i call the function

Comment: OK,  another idea: In your example output the string is surounded by spaces: \" 11001-111001 \", caused by `commaString = @" "" "`. Remove these spaces.

Comment: Btw, your statement ends on " || " what is probably not what you want.

Comment: Yes.i hv removed the spaces and the last ||. To removed ||, i used itemList.remove(itemList.Length - 3); Sorry forget to add that in my question.but still the same output

Comment: As already pointed out, this is the output from the debugger but not necessarily the real content of the string. Can you check if a query using the resulting string does the right thing?

Comment: Like showed in my question, if i hardcoded the variable, it works...but when debugged during runtime, the query will read the variable the way debugger's output.so this is wrong and cannot get the output from database

Comment: By hardcoding you mean `x => x.Code == "11001-111001" || x.Code == "11016-111001"`? That's a totally different approach since no strings are concatenated here.

Comment: Yes.thats the value i want...and i want to concatenate the string variable to be like that.but i stucked wih the back slash. really hv no idea how to do this.may be this cannot be done :(

Comment: I'm not sure how this concatenated value can help you because it's just a string but the above is source code. So what are you doing with the concatenated string? Feed it to a function?

Comment: Yup.going to put in the function, replace the hardcoded one...i am doing this to avoid from retrieving all records in table. Should retrieve the wanted records only. Need to minimize the waiting time to load

Comment: Can you post the piece of code that operates on the string?

Comment: sorry, i dont get wht u want. the string is from user input, and then i created the list to search thru the query

Comment: I want to know how this string is used to do a query. How do you parse it? I don't think you can use it in a Where() clause the same way as your original (hardcoded) query because it's just a string, not code.